# iPhone simulator => debugging terminated 

Tags: iphone, debugging

When I start my iPhone application it boots up fine, shows the first settings screen and all after I have given input and pressed save, the debug window says

> Debugging Terminated

without any hint to why in the crash logs.

First I thought it was my programming, but then I went ahead and tested the app on multiple 'real' iPhones and it never crashed.

Why does the simulator keeps crashing?

Comment: maybe a little less information :(

Comment: I don't have any other info, cause XCode isn't giving me any

Comment: Is the simulator app itself crashing or is it just your app in the simulator crashing? The difference is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common cause of crashes on the simulator but not the device and vice versa is using precompiled libraries that were compiled on the other hardware. Check if you've got something compile for ARM that is trying to run on the Intel.

Answer (score 1):

In XCode try Build > Clean All Targets

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting the simulator? iPhone Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings

Then do a clean build of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Annoying :)

Put NSLog statements around where you think that it's crashing and look at the output. That shoud give you more of an idea where the crash is occurring.

If that doesn't help, post the lines causing the crash in the question and see if anyone can help then.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

This tends to happen when you declare a variable and then use it without actually creating it. I would check variables you are using to make sure you are actually creating them before using (i.e. with alloc or the convenience methods).